# OpenXML Powerpoint - Rescale presentation after changing it's width/height

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is it possible to rescale the presentation after programatically changing it's width/height?
I would want a similar outcome as per doing it manually via powerpoint:
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Change-the-size-of-your-slides-040a811c-be43-40b9-8d04-0de5ed79987e

Edit:
I am already using [openxml power tools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) - that handles the merge for me. I just need to adjust the sizes of the shapes.

Edi2:
Attached are powepoint exexmplary files with the effect that i am aiming for. Again I am not looking for soklution to merge the files (because i already have that one) but just the one that helps me rescale the shapes on it.
[Examples](https://github.com/trzewior/MergeExamples)

Comment: It's possible. How difficult it is will depend on how thorough a job you need to do.  Note that StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. To get the best answers, you need to try it yourself, then ask here when you run into problems with your code.

Comment: I'm not looking for any code, im looking for a tip on how to implement this because I couldn't find any similar question nor did i find anything useful about scaling presentations.

Comment: I'd start by creating a copy of the original presentation, deleting all the content from each slide in the copy, then copying the content, a shape at a time, from each slide in the original presentation to the corresponding slide in the copy, reducing or enlarging its size and its top/left position as need be. Things get more complex for text, since you'll need to change not only the font size but the line spacing, paragraph spacing, possibly kerning and so on.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg That's what i unfortunately thought i had to do. I have one question tho, assuming i am copying a 16:9 slide to a 4:3 using powerpoint. Original presentation size was:
9144000x685800, copied slide came from 12192000x6858000. On original pres one of the shapes had sizes like that:
`<a:off x="537459" y="515462" />   
<a:ext cx="11117083" cy="600164" />`
and new one:
`<a:off x="403095" y="515462" />
<a:ext cx="8337812" cy="473206" />`
Why is it that it's changing only one of the cy's, while cx's are in a good proportions (0.75)?

Comment: It might help to explain this if we could see a sample 1-slide 16x9 presentation with this one shape on the slide.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I edited a question and included that one as well.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I'm getting odd results when I use PPT 2010 to copy/paste your 16x9 slide into the 4x3 presentation; the shapes are distorted (enlarged) vertically, but when I do the same thing in PPT 2016, the proportions are correct. Which version are you using?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg 2013

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Any followup on that?

Comment: I'm afraid not.